# Something is wrong in this video about Responsive Design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, safari

So I was watching [this](https://youtu.be/YBK_1WrM294) video about responsive design and something in that video is bothering me. At 2:59 he risizes the window to the large screen and then refreshes and then Safari downloads the `banner_large.jpg` and when he does the same thing with the medium and small screen sizes, then Safari downloads the `banner_medium.jpg` and `banner_small.jpg` respectively. But then one can see that he is able to resize the browser and the banners change accordingly (notice the 'jumps' of the image when the threshold reaches). So the question is that if Safari doesn't download the other two images then how is it able to display them? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

He has the `Network Requests` section selected in the `Web Inspector`. This would only show you when the page sends a request to the server to get a file. He had already resized the page at the beginning of the video, which would have requested the files at that time (assuming they weren't cached from a previous time). So, assuming that caching is turned on, when he resizes the page with the inspector open, it won't request the files again.

In order to show the file sizes, he refreshes the page, which forces the browser to re-download all of the files and show them in the `Web Inspector`. You can tell he's doing this because when he first opens the `Network Requests` section, it's empty (because nothing is being requested). Following this, he says, "And then hit reload" and he reloads the page which shows all of the files on the page being downloaded. You can tell that they're all being re-downloaded because in the `Cached` column, it says `No` for all files and it's displaying the contents for `index.html` and other files that would have been cached, such as css files and the background gradient.